# Update CRUD component in Angular not saving data

Tags: angular, typescript, json-server

Here is my update component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-update-person',
  templateUrl: './update-person.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update-person.component.css']
})
export class UpdatePersonComponent implements OnInit {
  id: number;
  data: object = {};
  // person = []; //ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
  // person = any; //ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: any is not defined
  person: any; //ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
  exist = false;
  personObj: object = {};
  private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}
  confirmationString: string = 'Person updated successfully !!';
  isUpdated: boolean = false;

  updatePerson = function(person) {
    this.personObj = {
      p_id: person.p_id,
      p_username: person.p_username,
      p_image: person.p_image
    };
    const url = `${'http://localhost:5555/person'}/${this.id}`;
    this.http
      .put(url, JSON.stringify(this.personObj), { headers: this.headers })
      .toPromise()
      .then(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      });
  };
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = +params['id'];
    });
    this.http
      .get('http://localhost:5555/person')
      .subscribe((res: Response) => {
        this.isUpdated = true;
        this.person = res;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.person.length; i++) {
          if (parseInt(this.person[i].id) === this.id) {
            this.exist = true;
            this.data = this.person[i];
            break;
          } else {
            this.exist = false;
          }
        }
      });
  }
}
```

This works without throwing any errors. However, after clicking the update button blank data is saved to my json server.

The think the issue is with `person: any;`. You can see a couple of other things I have tried with that person variable and the corresponding error I get.

Answer (score 1):

It is normally recommended that you put your data access code into a service, not a component.

I normally use post to create new data and put to update existing data.

My update method (in my data access service) looks like this:

```
  updateProduct(product: Product): Observable<Product> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    const url = `${this.productsUrl}/${product.id}`;
    return this.http.put<Product>(url, product, { headers: headers })
      .pipe(
        tap(() => console.log('updateProduct: ' + product.id)),
        // Return the product on an update
        map(() => product),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

Notice that I'm not stringifying the passed data. Nor am I converting the result to a promise.

Regarding your code:

1) Consider moving the data access code into a service.

2) Where are you using the `UpdatePerson` function? (Where is it being called?)

3) When building a function using the `function` keyword instead of an arrow function `=>`, the `this` becomes scoped to the function and you are not actually accessing the class-level `personObj`

4) I'm unclear on the need for both `person` and `personObj`?

If you would like some working sample code with create, update, and delete operations, you can find an example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-ReactiveForms/tree/master/APM

You can see/execute it in stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/deborahk-crud

Comment: Wow! Great post Deborah! Here is the repo I am working from https://github.com/ps0305/angularCRUD. Basically all I have changed is the model from product to person. I will check out the repo you shared and also study the suggestions you have made. Thank you!!!

Comment: In taking a quick look ... I assume that was meant to be more of a demo app and not an example of what you'd build for a real application. Best practice is to use a service for data access. From the Angular documentation: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#talk-to-the-server-through-a-service